# How many rounds of golf does the average golfer play?

Tags: trivia, statistics, golf

I'm looking for statistics that give me a sense of how many rounds of golf *the average golfer* plays, but am unable to find this so I'm wondering if any golfers here can anecdotally give me a sense of this number.

I did find this great infographic describing golfer demographic info, which definitely paints a great picture of the average golfer, but fails to mention how many rounds of golf the average golfer plays. http://www.golf.com/special-features/2009-survey-american-golfer

How many rounds of golf does the average golfer play?

Comment: The article you reference states: "The average *American* golfer...
• Is 46 years old • Practices one hour and 11 minutes per week • Has an average household income of $100,980 • **Plays 46 rounds per year** • Has probably called a penalty on himself (90 percent said they've done it at least once) • Has a handicap of 15.1 • Loses 1.3 balls per round • Has played for 23 years"

Comment: Wow, completely missed that. It's right in the opening paragraph. Thanks!

Comment: The problem in any kind of stat that you use is skewed by your definition of "golfer". Is a guy who plays once a year considered a "golfer"? If not, how many rounds are required to be a "golfer"? I could almost guarantee you that if their stats say the average handicap is 15.1 that it wouldn't include the very casual golfer.

Answer (score 1):

Ask 15 "average golfers", you'll get 16 answers. It all depends. From your article which Ed helpfully digested, the average American golfer plays 46 rounds a year. The average golfer also has a 15 handicap, which sounds like I might need to give it up.

Of course I'm not average in many ways:

> The average American golfer...
>
> - Is 46 years old *- I'll be 35 tomorrow*
> - Practices one hour and 11 minutes per week *- not happening with three kids under 5, I'm lucky to get to the range 4 or 5 times a year,
>     not counting warm-ups with a few hits at the club's range before a
>     round*
> - Has an average household income of $100,980 *- I wish. I make enough but not that much*
> - Spends $3000 a year on golf - *Pfft. The only club I've ever bought new is my putter, I play Noodles at a buck a ball instead of top-tier
>     $5 balls, I'm hitting the same irons I bought 5 years ago used, in a
>     bag I've had for nearly 10 back when there was a TopGolf range in
>     walking distance. Half my equipment was either a gift or a
>     hand-me-down. I don't even pay my own green fees, my in-laws pay less
>     to bring me along on their home course than they pay themselves. I I
>     don't think I've spent $3000 on the game to date*
> - Plays 46 rounds per year *- More like 20 for me*
> - Has probably called a penalty on himself (90 percent said they've done it at least once) - *Well yeah, them's the rules, but I've also
>     used my "underhand wedge" to clear a tree or rock, putted into holes
>     with the flag still in, and taken dozens of gimmes; when you're not
>     playing for money and a pace of play is enforced, you do what you
>     must*
> - Has a handicap of 15.1 *- 30-cap at least, my best round* ever *is a 102*
> - Loses 1.3 balls per round *- More like 3-6, though I haven't hit one in the water in months; I tend to lose them in tall grass under trees
>     just off the fairway, which annoys the heck out of me cause it would
>     be playable if I could just* find *the darn thing*
> - Has played for 23 years *- Only been playing actual rounds of golf for about 7 years, so I've got 16 more years of experience and 11 more
>     in age to step my game up to "average"*